# Delphi Fast(er) Lanczos resample

Tags: delphi, lanczos

I'd like to find some code for a very fast bitmap resampling using [Lanczos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lanczos_resampling) filter. Currently using this: http://pastebin.com/JxuqLXB9

I've been looking for a faster implementation, to no avail. Tried some implementations from GraphicsEx, Graphics32, madGraphics, JEDI, they were all slower than this.

Comment: 'tried some procs' - which one? Do you need only a faster Lanczos implementation or you have a specific problem and you want to solve it?

Comment: I just want a faster Lanczos, not related to any specific problem/situation.

Comment: Maybe you'd need to recompile it in Win64 using SSE
Or maybe you'd better ditch Delphi and use some C DLL with Delphi wrapper

Comment: the example linked by RBA is quite nice, got it from 15ms with the original resample down to ~10 per iteration in my sample, so around 33% faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer should improve the timing of your scaling process -  [Scale an image nicely in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976116/scale-an-image-nicely-in-delphi/1976171#1976171).

I do not have any other knowledge about a faster implementation of the Lanczos resampling.