# Draw Transparent Scaled PNG

Tags: delphi, winapi, png, delphi-xe, image-scaling

I have a large  (300x300px) PNG image which I need to rescale. In an other [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976116/scale-an-image-nicely-in-delphi) I read about `StretchBlt` and `HALFTONE` in order for better scaling.

My problem is how do I draw the  PNG image transparent, or at least paint the black corners white?

[image]

As you can see on the attached image I get black corners.

And here is the original image:
[image]
Here is what I've tried so far.

```
unit MainU;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, ExtCtrls;

type
  TFormMain = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  FormMain: TFormMain;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}
uses
  Pngimage;

type
  TIRButton = class(TImage)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  public
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
  end;

  TGraphicControlAcess = class(TGraphicControl);
  TGraphicAcess = class(TGraphic);

  THalfTonePngImage = class(TPngImage)
  protected
    procedure Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect); override;
  end;

  { TIRButton }

constructor TIRButton.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Center := True;
  Proportional := True;
end;

procedure TIRButton.Paint;
var
  ParentCanvas: TCanvas;
begin
  ParentCanvas := TGraphicControlAcess(Self).Canvas;
  TGraphicAcess(Picture.Graphic).Draw(ParentCanvas, DestRect);
end;

{ THalfTonePngImage }

procedure THalfTonePngImage.Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect);
var
  p: TPoint;
  dc: HDC;
begin
  dc := ACanvas.Handle;
  GetBrushOrgEx(dc, p);
  SetStretchBltMode(dc, HALFTONE);
  SetBrushOrgEx(dc, p.X, p.Y, @p);

  ACanvas.Brush.Color := clWhite;
  ACanvas.FillRect(Classes.Rect(0, 0, Width, Height));

  StretchBlt(
    dc, 0, Rect.Top, Rect.Right - Rect.Left, Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top,
    Canvas.Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height, ACanvas.CopyMode
    );
end;

procedure TFormMain.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Image: THalfTonePngImage;
begin
  Image := THalfTonePngImage.Create;
  Image.LoadFromFile('X200IR_11_EmgBrake.png');

  with TIRButton.Create(Self) do
  begin
    Width := 100;
    Height := 100;
    Picture.Assign(Image);
    Parent := Self;
    Anchors := [akLeft, akTop, akRight, akBottom];
  end;

  Image.Free;
end;

end.
```

Comment: You want the entire image to be transparent, or 'not draw the corners'? The latter would be a problem because they are black, and I suppose while "draw *everything* that is black in white" will do that but is not the solution you are looking for. You would need a mask that covers the corners. Really, easiest way to get rid of the corners is to open the image in an image editor.

Comment: Preferable I would like the corners to be transparent, and if thats hard to do then the cornors to be white.

Comment: The image is a screenshot of what you get at the moment. Can you also show the original image? If you cannot edit the original image, can you use another image as a mask?

Comment: The screen shot is what I get today. And yes i can use an other image as a mask. I'll add the original image.

Comment: First I suggest you derive `TIRButton` from `TGraphicControl` (not `TImage`) which already exposes `Canvas` and suitable for such control. Second, I think `TPngImage` **should** support drawing scaled transparent PNG by design via `.Draw(ACanvas: TCanvas; const Rect: TRect)`. At least "older" [`TPngObject`](http://pngdelphi.sourceforge.net) supports it...

Comment: Thanks for you advise @kobik but I needed to draw my PNGImage the way I do, else it won't rescale nicly. About derive from TGraphicControl you got a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The corners of the source image are transparent. It's not visible in the correct image because the white background. `StretchBlt` doesn't support transparency.  Since it doesn't, transparent pixels are indistinguishable from black. (If the ARGB color is `FF 00 00 00` and we remove the alpha channel, we're left with `00 00 00`)

You need to use [`TransparentBlt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145141.aspx).

For reference this is the image when placed on a green background. It makes it easier to see the transparency.

[image]