# Stretching TSpeedButton by GDI+ for HDPI

Tags: delphi, gdi+

Unfortunately Delphi does not scale `TSpeedButton.Glyph`. The button surface scaled, but the size of the glyph stay the original. I use the naive approach to scale the bitmap by `TCanvas.StretchDraw` but the result is disgusting.
I search the internet and I found the `GDI+` library where I can define the quality.
The soul of the solution is the `TIGPGraphics.DrawImage( image, .... )`
But here image is an `TIGPImage` instance. It has no constructor with a `TBitmap` parameter, it has no property to copy a `TBitmap` into it. I don't want to stream the bitmap just to pass it for the `TIGPImage` constructor. Can somebody help me to create the GP image by a `TBitmap` contents and stretched draw it to another `TBitmap` (SpeedButtonX.glyph).
I don't stick to GDI plus, I interested in other solutions as well while the result will be better then with `TCanvas.StrechDraw`.

I downloaded the GPIPlusMod library from here : https://github.com/jackdp/IGDIPlusMod

Comment: In my experience I always add a TGlyph to a TSpeedButton. It allows me to place it where I want and resize it how I want.

Comment: Have you considered using the `Images`+`ImageIndex` properties instead of `Glyph`? That way, you can assign a `TVirtualImageList` to the button and let it handle scaling images for you. [Supporting high-DPI images with the Image Collection and Virtual ImageList components](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Supporting_high-DPI_images_with_the_Image_Collection_and_Virtual_ImageList_components)

Comment: @RemyLebeau
The program now uses static glyphs on the TSpeedButtons. But if TVirtualImageList does the work I modify the prog. The program uses TImageLists as well. Should I replace them with virtual ones?

Comment: @SOLIDDevelopper read the documentation I linked to

Answer (score -1):

Check my answer here how to resize a bitmap with interpolation:

[Nicely scale image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69191941/nicely-scale-image-withour-external-libraries/69194250#69194250)